# Best way to insert into table with using join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a project table which is connected to a media table on their id and mediable_id (`project.id = media.mediable_id`).

Each project has a column called `media_id`. I want to copy the data of all existing media and only change the `mediable_id` field to match that of the `media_id` field in the `projects` table.

Current example:

The dutch project id = 145, the english project = 945

Project

```
id 945
media_id 145
```

Media

```
id 11039
mediable_id 145
```

Now there should be a new copy in media where the mediable_id is the id of the english project.

So:

```
id 11040
mediable_id 945
```

Above entry should be a copy of media id 11039 except for the incremented id ofcourse and the mediable_id now having that of the english project.

How can I achieve this with SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
INSERT INTO media (mediable_id)
SELECT project.id
FROM project
JOIN media ON project.media_id = media.mediable_id
```

As I understand `media.id` is autoincremented primary key, so it will be assigned automatically.

Comment: Thanks this works kind of but all values are empty. I need a copy of the media row, not an empty new one. The only things changing in the exact copy are the id and the mediable_id